# All fullscreen applications run slow on linux, but fine in windows

Tags: linux, video

I have an Asus G73JH-X1, which is having a weird issue in all linux OS's that I have tried so far.  I am getting very bad framerate on everything that's fullscreen, without using any CPU nor GPU. It is currently connected to a TV through a VGA cord, but I have tried connecting it with HDMI and had same results.

During youtube playback of 360p video in normal window i get full FPS, however as soon as I change it to fullscreen, it becomes choppy and I get 2-3 fps at a time. Video playback on VLC, and any application in fullscreen mode is having the same issue as well.

CPU usage does not go above 10% at any point, and CPU temperature stays at ~70C max. GPU temperature does not get above ~75C either. At the moment I am running Manjaro, however I have tried many other distros and had the same issue.

Tried using open source ati-drivers and proprietary ATI ones, which had no effect on FPS. Tried lowering resolution to something very small, which had no effect. Tried Using a different display, cord, and messing with various video output settings, which had no effect.

With the exact same setup, I am having no issues at all on windows, however, if possible I would like to get it working on Linux. Any idea on what might be wrong with this thing?

Comment: What graphic card do you have? Usually, Nvidia GPUs have problems running with Linux and your only hope is to install proprietary drivers and hope that they work (for me they didn't and screwed up my installation). Intel GPUs tend to run greatly, and I don't have any personal experience with others.

Comment: It has Radeon 5870m. Installing proprietary drivers did not improve anything.